# "this" is undefined inside my Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, mobx

There is a problem with my small todo app. Every time I try to delete an item there is an error `Cannot read property 'todos' of undefined`

Why `this` is bound inside `addTodo` but not `removeTodo` ?

The trigger is done here: `<button onClick={() => removeTodo(id)}> X </button>`

Demo on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jondion/hphuqsmz/2/)

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `removeTodo` into a property initialized arrow function or use the `action.bound` decorator. You also have to use MobX array [**replace**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html) so you don't lose the reference:

```
removeTodo = (id) => {
  var filtered = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
  this.todos.replace(filtered);
}
```

Or:

```
@action.bound
removeTodo(id) {
  var filtered = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
  this.todos.replace(filtered);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tholle it's now working. I simply added ```@action.bound()``` to my function and everything is working as expected.

Comment: @jonathandion Great!